# I am getting Problem with npm any Command same error

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, npm-install

**I am getting Problem with npm any Comma

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68rlF.png)

[image]

nd same error.**

Comment: Suggest you to please read the error messages. and Google it. apart from try your network connection as this is what error messages suggest.

Comment: Also, Explain your question a bit more. avoid putting such screenshots, copy and paste error messages instead.

Answer (score -1):

The error says you have network connection problems.
Make sure you are connected to the internet and try switching off your proxy and try again.
If you need your proxy make sure it is working correctly.